# How to detect whether there's a newer version of my iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I would like to provide an alert within my iOS app if there is a new version available from iTunes. I can't find an API for this. Is this possible?

Comment: Don't understand the close/down-votes. It is (was) badly worded but it's a valid question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a good argument that you don't need to do anything. The App Store app will already notify users when updates are available.

However, if you want to do it anyway, there's a project on GitHub called [iVersion](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion) that does most of the heavy lifting for you. (Not tried it myself, but it looks pretty good.)

Comment: iVersions looks interesting - thanks for that link =)

Comment: Well, it's a legitimate question I think - there are also some things I would like to do to inform users that there is a new version, and/or give them some information over a new version before they download it. The notification of the App Store app is useless in the sense that if you have 50+ apps, there are always 10+ updates, and normally you just accept them without looking at what they are about. And indeed a nice link :-).

Comment: Thanks All, My requirement is to show update button (within my app) enable whenever a new version of same app available on app store. I just want to know there is any method API or something like that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Stephen, look good will test it and let you know. Thanks Once Again..