# How to detect a MobileFirst iOS app's new version in app store and direct updating programatically?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We would like to make a version checking function by clicking a `version checking` button inside our MobileFirst app. So how to do a detecting of new version of a MobileFirst iOS app for both appstore version and DirectUpdate version.

For direct updating, it's easy to trigger when client is first loaded (now it works great in our `initOptions.js` file). But also it seems that `wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate` works only when the app is loaded. To trigger it, we have to quit the app and re-initialise it. Can we do it programatically anywhere/anytime within app?

And for appstore version update checking (in fact, this won't be frequent), there are many [native ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583256/how-to-detect-whether-theres-a-newer-version-of-my-ios-application) but is there a hybrid or MobileFirst way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the App Store version check you can implement a Cordova plug-in: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/adding-native-functionality/

For Direct Update, you cannot change its mode during runtime. You can however change its mode to `perRequest` in authenticationConfig.xml: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-quickly-update-application/